# Create-react-app livereload with Docker on Windows

Tags: reactjs, docker, create-react-app

I'm trying to run docker on Windows 10 (Linux Containers Mode) to run react development workspace. I managed to run React app boilerplate but livereloading is not working.

Here's some details:

1. Dockerfile is exposing both 5000 and 35729 ports
2. Files are mounted and created inside the container via `docker exec` and `create-react-app .` commands
3. WS request status is 101 (that's correct)

#### Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

#installing react app first
RUN npm install -g create-react-app

VOLUME [ "/application" ]

#First example was EXPOSE 3000 35729
EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 35729
```

1. **Build command:** `docker build . -t react-image`
2. **Run command:** `docker run -d -p 3000:3000 -p 35729:35729 -v %PATH_TO_APP_FOLDER%\application:/application --name react-container react-image`
3. **Exec command:** `docker exec -it react-container bash`

Then inside the container:

- `cd application`
- `create-react-app .`
- `yarn start`

#### OUTPUT:

> Compiled successfully!
>
> You can now view application in the browser.
>
> Local:            http://localhost:3000/   On Your Network: 
>   http://172.17.0.2:3000/
>
> Note that the development build is not optimized. To create a
>   production build, use yarn build.

Once I open: http://localhost:3000 everything seems to work fine. If I change files from my host machine files are also changed inside the container (checked with `cat App.js`). But changing files doesn't trigger webpack re-compiling and livereload.

Any suggestions?

Please let me know if I need to provide more details. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by setting `watchOptions.poll` to true inside the webpack config:
[References](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/#watchoptions-poll)